# Database error "Can't connect to MySQL server on" in AWS lambda execution

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I have a Lambda that I have a python script running on it, it reads the secret and query some data from rds database, it gave me this error then I tried to run the script:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "errorType": "DatabaseError",
...........
}
```

Does anyone ever seen this? I suspect I need to add the lambda on the VPC, or it doesn't have the correct security group attached, just wondering how to fix it and how to make changes in Terraform? Thanks.

Comment: You are right, you have to add the lambda function to the same VPC where the RDS is, and in the RDS allow connections from the VPC

Comment: Could you send me more detailed info please, how can I find this vpc and how can I make rds to allow the connection? I'm not very familiar with side of knowledge...

Comment: You should know which RDS instance your Lambda is trying to connect to, so go to RDS in the AWS Console and look at the config for that RDS instance. It will tell you its VPC. Then read the [public docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html) on how to set up Lambda to run in a VPC and access the database.